# API is not enabled for the project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm receiving this error again and again while running my project
"API my-api.endpoints.example-project-12345.cloud.goog is not enabled for the project"

Can anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you sent an API key in the request, an error message like "API my-api.endpoints.example-project-12345.cloud.goog is not enabled for the project" indicates that the API key was created in a different Google Cloud project than the API. To fix this, you can either create the API key[1] in the same Google Cloud project that the API is associated with, or you can enable the API[2] in the Google Cloud project that the API key was created in.

Refer the document  for more information :

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api